# GitLab CI failing after turning it off then on on a project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops, gitlab-ci-runner

I have the fork of an open source project. When I forked the project I had CI on. Then I thought that letting the CI run on my fork will cost me money if I make too much changes and push them. Later on I learned that if the project is public it won't cost me money and the CI results are needed for my commits to be merged. I turned back the CI. Now when the request  GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/user happens the answer is 401 {message: 401 Unauthorized}. This is what I see in the log. The run is not happening on my local machine but on GitLab's server.

What can I do in this situation? Did I forget some setting?

I searched for possible solutions on the internet. Those who had the same problem, have had it on their local shell, meaning they tried to make an http request and forget to add token or did not generate the right kind of token. In some solutions I saw the yaml file was edited. I also can't do that because the job runs just fine for others. The problem can't be in the workflow itself.